# Updating TextView with clock

Tags: java, android, timer, textview, clock

I have been trying to create a program that will output a working digital clock that will allow me to quickly access the date and time. I have the code to parse the time, however, I'm having difficulty updating the textview. I have this:

```
    `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    timer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);

    time = new Time();
    time.setToNow();

    timeString = time.toString();
    changeTime = Parser(timeString);


    time.setToNow();
    timeString = time.toString();
    changeTime = Parser(timeString);

    timer.setText(changeTime);  
    } 
    private String Parser(String time){

    String year = time.substring(0, 4);
    String month = time.substring(4,6);
    String day = time.substring(6, 8);
    String hour = time.substring(9,11);
    String minute = time.substring(11, 13);
    String second = time.substring(13, 15);

    String finalTime = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + " " + day + " " + month + " "  + year;
    //String finalTime = second;
    return finalTime;


}`
```

How do I put this in a loop to constantly update the textview.

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: you can use `Thread`,`TimerTask` or `Handler.postdelayed` for updating TextView constantly instead of using loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a Handler to update the TextView on the UI thread.

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
 @Override
 public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    time = new Time();
    time.setToNow();

    timeString = time.toString();
    changeTime = Parser(timeString); 
    timer.setText(changeTime);  
 }
};
```

Start a TimeTask that will update your TextView

```
int initialDelay = 1000; //first update in miliseconds
int period = 5000;      //nexts updates in miliseconds       

Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
  public void run() {
      Message msg = new Message();
      mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
  }
};
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, initialDelay, period);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad practice to start updating the view with never ending handler messages (try it an look at the CPU level of your process).
The better and more elegant way is to register a `BroadcastReceiver` which will trigger the update.

```
public class Clock extends LinearLayout {

    private Calendar mCalendar;
    private LinearLayout mLayoutTime;
    private TextView mAMPMText;
    private TextView mDateText;
    private TextView mTimeText;
    private View mSendFeedback;
    private boolean mAttached;

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm");

    public Clock(final Context context, int layoutResourceID, int dateResId, int meResId,int amPmResId) {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResourceID, null);
        addView(view, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        mAMPMText = (TextView) view.findViewById(amPmResId);
        mTimeText = (TextView) view.findViewById(timeResId);
        mDateText = (TextView) view.findViewById(dateResId);    
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        if (!mAttached) {
            mAttached = true;
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);

            getContext().registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, filter, null, mHandler);
        }

        // NOTE: It's safe to do these after registering the receiver since the receiver always runs
        // in the main thread, therefore the receiver can't run before this method returns.

        // The time zone may have changed while the receiver wasn't registered, so update the Time
        mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        // Make sure we update to the current time
        onTimeChanged();
        updateView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        if (mAttached) {
            getContext().unregisterReceiver(mIntentReceiver);
            mAttached = false;
        }
    }

    private void updateView(){
        mTimeText.setText(timeFormatter.format(mCalendar.getTime()));
        mDateText.setText(dateFormatter.format(mCalendar.getTime()));
        mAMPMText.setText(mCalendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0 ? "AM" : "PM");
    }

    private void onTimeChanged() {
        mCalendar.setTime(new Date());

        updateContentDescription(mCalendar);
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED)) {
                String tz = intent.getStringExtra("time-zone");
                mCalendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz));
            }

            onTimeChanged();

            updateView();
        }
    };

    private void updateContentDescription(Calendar calendar) {
        setContentDescription(calendar.toString());
    }
}
```

The layout (can be done better)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:includeFontPadding="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/am_pm_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AM" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a timer thread. You can also simplify your time and date conversions by using `Calendar`, and can optimize your String creation by using `format`. This example will update your `TextView` every second (1000ms):

```
Timer t = new Timer();
timer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);

t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        final String finalTime = String.format(Locale.US, "%d:%d:%d %d/%d/%d", c.get(Calendar.HOUR), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE), c.get(Calendar.SECOND), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.YEAR));

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    timer.setText(finalTime);
                }
            });
    }

}, 1000, 1000); //Initial Delay and Period for update (in milliseconds)
```

Comment: this seems to make the formatted time appear, however, it doesn't seem to update. Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @JJJ1106, Yes - I fixed my post. You need to create the `Calendar` instance inside of the `TimerTask`. If this works well for you, consider accepting this as the answer because of its simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily with the help of a thread in android but as you want to access the ui so threads won't work help you. you should better choose handlers or timertask

However async tasks also run on Non-ui thread so make an handler inside a timertask..

```
Timer t=Timer();

    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(new Runnable()
        {
    public void run(){
    Handler h=new Handler(getMainLooper());
    h.post(new Runnable(
){public void run(){
//get the time here and set the textview here as here it has access to the main ui
}});
    }
    }
    ), long delay, Long period);
```

Sorry for bad code formatting ...but it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

If the operation is not time consuming, it is recommended to use `Handler` instead of `Timer` or `Thread`. The `Handler` works in the current thread and does not create a new thread, which saves some memory usage. It also saves some CPU usage by reducing the number of CPU polling threads. Moreover, Android's thread `Looper` and clock `SysClock` is optimized to consume almost no resources when waiting.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) // using the main thread to update view
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run(){
        tick()
    }
}
void tick(){
    Date date = Date()
    String text = date.toString() // or using SimpleDateFormat
    textView.setText(text)
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000)
}
```

Remember to end it manually.

```
void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
}
```