# How to implement TextView Clock using data binding?

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, textview, android-databinding

One solution would be to create a [TimerTask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16154223/3061967) which updates a LiveData variable 'time'. Then assign that variable to a TextView using data binding. Is there a better way of implementing this?

Comment: Do you have to use a TextView + databinding? Generally I think TextClock would be better suited for this usecase: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock .

Comment: I need the text to uniformly autosize. As TextClock does not inherit AppCompat TextView, the autosizing will not be backwards compatible.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really recommended to use `LiveData` for never ending tasks. The purpose of `LiveData` is for lifecycle automation. When the life cycle of a view is over, the data of view is no longer updated.

However, whether you use `Handler`, `Thread`, or `Timer`, you will inevitably have to manually stop them at the end of view's lifecycle. This makes it meaningless to use `LiveData` for lifecycle automation.

In addition, the core role of `LiveData` is to cache the view's data, ensuring that when you leave the view for a short time and return, you can restore the view to its previous state without having to reload the data source.
Date variables, however, do not need to be cached.